# Lost Android Apk Keystore. Creating new App. How do I force users to uninstall the old one

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, google-play

So I've lost the keystore file for my Xamarin App when my machine crashed. After cursing myself for not saving it, I've finally accepted that I need to create new app in playstore. I know I can unpublish an app in play store. What I wanted to know is, how can I tell the user to uninstall the old app and install the new one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not change the old app in any way, so you are limited in what you can do and you can not force the users to do anything...

Personally I would not un-publish the old one *at first*, but it really depends upon the number of users and the reviews the app has. ;-)

If your old app has a number of good to great reviews and a better than avg. rating, keep it listed until your new app is at least equal. Google Play Store ranking algorithms use rating and reviews (among other things), so do not throw this away until your new app can match the old one...

You can update the old Application description in the Play Store without changing the `.apk`:

- Add additional content to your old description that users *surfing* in the store should install the new app. Remember the first 167 characters are used in search results and becomes the `metacontent` so do not waste those characters...
- Include a Url link in your old app description to your new app in the store (`play.google.com`). This link will be clickable in a browser, but not in the Play App on a device
- Make sure to label your new app that is a ***new*** application as new and improved-style wording will catch the eye of a user in the Play Store
- Also for existing users, make sure the your installed *new* app icon and name are different and standout from old app (you want to *visually* drive people to your new app once it is on the device)
- If someone installs your new old and still has your old app installed, your new app can check via the `PackageManager` and prompt the user to uninstall it:

  ```
  var pm = Application.Context.PackageManager;
  var apps = pm.GetInstalledPackages(Android.Content.PM.PackageInfoFlags.MatchAll);
  foreach (var app in apps)
  {
      if (app.PackageName == "com.sushihangover.SomeOldApp")
      {
          // Display dialog to tell user to uninstall old app...
      }
  }
  ```
- If you old app has any `New News` section that you can publish content to, ability to receive a remote notification and display a message to the user, etc...  make use of it to notify the user that there is a brand new app available via the Play Store....
- Backup those new keys ;-)

Comment: Thanks. If only Xamarin had some kind of documentation to save these keys :(, I never knew how important these keys were....

Comment: I thought there was some notes about that on Xamarin's site... Google has a section in their docs about that : https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#secure-key

Comment: No they dont. A bug has been raised. Look at this https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/272312

Comment: I feel your pain, I have had clients that lost access to their certificates (non-Xamarin based in those cases). I just read the thread and bug report you linked... personally I do not believe the certs should ***EVER*** be stored in the solution/project/version control, etc... Yes, Xamarin should have a note about it and link you to the Android documentation. but losing control of your release certificates by copying it everywhere is sooooo wrong, thus any ex-employee, consultant (like me), or newbie employee/dev that had/has access to your code also would have your publishing certificates...